# How can I change the initial ViewController in LaunchScreen with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I want to check whether the user is logged in or not, if the user is logged in, then bring him to main screen, or show the welcome screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do in Launch Screen, but you can achieve same in AppDelegate's method `didFinishLauchingWithOption`, there you can check if user logged in or not and set the root view controller and don't set initialViewController in storyboard. 
It should be something like this

```
    NSString *identifier = isLoggedIn ? @"IdentifierForVC1" : @"IdentifierForVC2";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: identifier];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

Code is not tested in an editor may have some 
Swift code should be like this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! UIViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: Can you give some code example? Thank you very much!

Comment: Um, I mean Swift code. I really don't know how to write objective-c code

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot!!! (I changed the line `self.windows?` into `self.window`, I thinks is swift 2.0 new syntax because it says the self don't have a property called `windows`)

Comment: No its not syntax it was typo on my end, it should be windo

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier")
   let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
   self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in Launch Screen but can do in AppDelegate

for Swift 4

```
 if userLoggedIn == True {
        //Do something 
        } else {
        //Do something
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value:Bool  ,forKey:"loggedIn")  //This will save the bool value to your UserDefaults
      }
```

---

---

Now Go to your AppDelegate

---

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

           self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


     if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(for key: "loggedIn")) == true {
         let welcomeVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeVC") as! WelcomeVC
            self.window?.rootViewController = newRootVC

            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
         let loginVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! LoginVC
            self.window?.rootViewController = newRootVC

            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
return true
    }
```

---

Happy Coding
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**Write this code in AppDelegate Swift 4.0**

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` pass your viewController to `self.launch(rootController: ViewController())`

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
    self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
 }
```

**Write this code in AppDelegate Swift 5.0 Xcode 11.0**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene{

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            let rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! UINavigationController

            window.rootViewController = rootViewController
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, in your AppDelegate.swift,

```
self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("{INSERT_STORYBOARD_ID_HERE}") as? UIViewController
```